# Turn bullets back "on" after a Compass Reset

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, css-reset

I have a site that's using SCSS and Compass.  I used the Compass reset at the top of my SCSS file, `@import 'compass/reset';` and it's worked fine.

I now have an unordered list that I actually DO want the default bullets on.  However, no matter what I've tried so far, no bullets.

```
.content {
    padding: 10px;
    ul {
        list-style: disc;
        li {
            list-style: disc;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?  How to override the reset for this list?

Comment: Open it up in firefox and use firebug to see what rules are overriding the list-style: disc rule.

Comment: Oddly enough, it worked in Firefox right away.  Was not working in Safari 6.  So I quit Safari, relaunched and the it took.  Maybe the cache did not purge even though I emptied it.

Comment: If it works now then it was just a caching of the file.  You can change the settings of your browser to get a new version of the page everytime FYI so you don't run into these issues again.  Or you can add a querystring parameter to your css file when you link it in the HTML so the browser is forced to get a new version.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `list-style-type` instead. some browsers may be able to deal with `list-style` though.

Answer (score 0):

for me looks like you need to add left padding and list style type to your ul tag.

```
ul {
   list-style-type: circle;
   padding-left: 20px;
   }
```